# How to prove this set is convex set?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, hilbert-spaces

For Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ and for bounded linear operators $T, A.$ How to prove this given set is convex.

$$W=\{\lambda\in\mathbb{C}:  \exists\  \{x_{n}\}\in \mathcal{H}\  \text{with} \ \ \|x_{n}\|=1, \  \text{such that} \ \  \langle{Tx_{n}},{Ax_{n}}\rangle\to \lambda  ,\|Tx_{n}\|\to \|T\|. \} $$

We can easily see that this given set is non-empty as $T,A$ are bounded linear opertor.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried using the definition? What happens?

Comment: yes, but for the convex combination of two elements. Not able to find the sequence of unit vector that satisfy these properties.